# Given a non-negative integer, find the indexes of all the bits which are set to 1

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is what I'm doing:

```js
function getIndexes(n) {
    return n
        .toString(2)
        .split("")
        .map((c, i) => [c, i])
        .filter(([c, _]) => c == "1")
        .map(([_, i]) => i)
    ;
}

console.log(getIndexes(6));
console.log(getIndexes(7));
console.log(getIndexes(42));
```

Explanation:

1. Convert the input number into a binary string
2. Convert the binary string into an array of characters
3. Map each character to a `[character, index]` tuple
4. Filter (keep only) the tuples whose character is `"1"`
5. Map each tuple to the index of that tuple

It feels a bit of an overkill.

Is there a more standard way to achieve that?

I care less about performance and more about using something cleaner and/or custom.

Thanks!

Comment: The indexes are returned MSB to LSB, by the way, but I care less about that either. I can easily reverse their order via `retVal.slice().reverse()`. Or even just by adding `.reverse()` after `.split("")` I suppose.

Comment: _"Is there a more standard way to achieve that?"_ - what's a "standard way"? The way you're achieving it now seems perfectly reasonable, especially if you don't care about performance.

Comment: Is this for a byte, word, or no upper limit?

Comment: @Yogi: Any non-negative integer up to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: I do not understand the link between your question and the code you supplied... given a binary representation of an integer `1000110011000` you want the index of each bit that is set to one ?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Could you add the range clarification to your question, please?

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: "*The indexes are returned MSB to LSB*" - which makes them unusable, since you don't know where the MSB is. `getIndexes(6)` has the same result as `getIndexes(3)`. You *need* to `.reverse()` your array

Answer (score 2):

If I well understood what you want to achieve, here is an alternative solution:

```
function getIndexes(n) {

  const result = [];

  const long_n = BigInt(n);

  for(let i = 0n; i < 64n; ++i) {

    if((long_n >> i) & 1n)  result.push(Number(i));

  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Edited to reach up to 64 bits, but stop when required. Anyway there may be more elegant way than calling Math.pow each iteration, but OP says it doesn't care about performances...

Comment: In JS, all bitwise operations are *only* done on 32 bit numbers. If a number is bigger, then it gets forcefully truncated. For demonstration: `2147483647 | 0` is `2147483647` however `2147483648 | 0` is `-2147483648`

Comment: Oh ! I wasn't aware of this limitation...

Comment: @VLAZ to be precise, all bitwise operations on *Number* values are done as 32 bit integers. However, you can do arbitrary bitwise operations on *BigInt* values as well, all it takes is to convert `n` to a `BigInt(n)`

Comment: Ok, using BigInt it seems to work as attended